# Can't trigger Controller from anchor in .Net Core Razor

Tags: c#, html, .net

I'm trying to implement logout function but it won't trigger the controller cause i tried to debug it. I never used mvc before though so i can't really tell what is wrong in this.

this controller is inside Controllers folder

```
 [Authorize]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> LogOut()
    {
        Request.HttpContext.Session.Remove("Nome");
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync();
        return RedirectToPage("/Login");
    }
}
```

and this razor view for trigger

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http

@{
<aside class="control-sidebar control-sidebar-dark">
    <!-- Control sidebar content goes here -->
    <div class="p-3">
        <div class="row py-2">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <img src="/Images/default-profile.png" class="img-circle elevation-2" width="50" alt="User Image" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row py-2">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <h5>
                    @Context.Session.GetString("Nome")
                </h5>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row py-2">
            <div class="col-sm-12 custom-hiddenbar-link">
                <a asp-action="LogOut" asp-controller="Controllers/Account" class="text-white">

                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt ml-2"></i>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            Terminar Sessão
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</aside>
```

}

what is wrong in this code?

Comment: You can probably just do `asp-controller="Account"` which might resolve it.

Comment: This worked but it's weird i tried before and didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the answer. Needed to add this on startup

```
 app.UseMvc(routes =>
           {
               routes.MapRoute(
                   name: "default",
                   template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
           });
```